# Programmatically delete app data on ios from command line

Tags: javascript, ios

I know you can do something like this on Android using `adb shell pm clear <package>` but not sure how to do this for ios.

Comment: Not possible unless jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

For install:

```
ideviceinstaller -i testApp.ipa
```

For uninstall:

```
ideviceinstaller -U com.testPackage.testApp
```

Tool: **ideviceinstaller**